# How to modify a header in a file?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn the basics of dealing with files in R. I'm trying to change a header. I tried `writeLines` function, but it writes a line and deletes the rest of the file instead of just modifying the header ;/ Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Here's my code

```
A<-data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3,4), X2=c(5,6,7,8), X3=c(9,10,11,12))
write.table(A, file="file.txt", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE) #I create a file.

napis<-paste("Col1","Col2","Col3", sep="\t") #This is going to be the new header.
connection<-file("file.txt", open="w") #I open a connection to write.
writeLines(napis, con=connection) #I'm trying to overwrite a line.
close(connection)
```

But when I open the file it only contains the new header :(

Answer (score 0):

R functions that write to files can either overwrite previously generated content, or be written to append at the bottom of files previously written. By changing the order of execution in the code from the question, and adding a few new arguments to `write.table()` we can produce the desired result.

Write the header first, then use `append = TRUE` and `column.names = FALSE` in `write.table()`.

```
A<-data.frame(X1=c(1,2,3,4), X2=c(5,6,7,8), X3=c(9,10,11,12))

napis<-paste("Col1","Col2","Col3", sep="\t") #This is going to be the new header.
connection<-file("file.txt", open="w") #I open a connection to write.
writeLines(napis, con=connection) #I'm trying to overwrite a line.
close(connection)
write.table(A, file="file.txt", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
            quote = FALSE,appen = TRUE) #I create a file.
```

...and the output file, `file.txt` looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1   5   9
2   6   10
3   7   11
4   8   12
```

To confirm accuracy, we read the file back into R as a data frame and print.

```
> B <- read.table("file.txt",header = TRUE)
> B
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    5    9
2    2    6   10
3    3    7   11
4    4    8   12
>
```

Comment: Yea, but what if the file I want to modify already exist and is very, very large?

Comment: @PLrc - R functions that operate on files in the operating system aren't designed to support "edit in place" operations. If you want to use different column names for a large file, it's easier to skip the headings with an argument (e.g. `skip = ` in `read.table()`) and set them manually in your R code (e.g. `col.names` argument also in `read.table()`.